# How can I display the start/end dates in modal?

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar

I want to edit the start time and end time, but when I click the modal the times don't show up, But the title does. Why is this? Is there something I'm missing?

```
eventClick: function (event) {
  $('#updateModal').modal('show');
  console.log(event)
  $("#id").val(event.id);
  $("#title").val(event.title);
  $("#start").val(event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
  $("#end").val(event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
}
```

Result from the edit modal when clicked

[image: Result from the edit modal when clicked]

Comment: are you using some date picker. If so then simply setting value might now work. Search for appropriate function from that plugin.

Comment: @JitendraYadav Yes, I am using the "datetime-local" type for storing and displaying. 
I also, tried to install moments to see if it displayed, but nothing. I'm still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is looking for an answer to this and everything else didn't work, a friend helped me and found a solution.

```
 eventClick: function (event) {
                if(event) {
                    $.ajax({
                        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                        type: "PUT",
                        datatype: 'JSON',
                        url: SITEURL + '/fullcalendar/edit',
                        data: "&id=" + event.id,
                        success: function (response) {
                            event = JSON.parse(response)

                            $('#start').val(formatEventDate(event.start))
                            $('#end').val(formatEventDate(event.end))

                            console.log(event)
                            $('#title').val(event.title)
                        }

                    });
                    $('#updateModal').modal('show');
                }
function formatEventDate(date){
        eventArr = date.split(' ')
        eventDate = eventArr[0]
        eventTime = eventArr[1].substr(0,5)
        return eventDate +'T'+ eventTime
    }
```

This is the controller edit function.

```
 public function edit(Request $request){
    $event = Event::find($request->id);
    return json_encode($event);
}
```

This is the route.

```
 Route::put('fullcalendar/edit', 'CalendarController@edit');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `datetime-local` accepts value in following format.

> ***Local date and time***: The following parts, in exactly the following order:
>
> - A date.
> - The literal string "T".
> - A time.

```
Example:
1985-04-12T23:20:50.52
1996-12-19T16:39:57
```

Format that string as follow

```
event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: ` $('#updateModal').modal('show');
                                console.log(event)
                                $("#id").val(event.id);
                                $("#title").val(event.title);
                                $("#start").val(event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
                                $("#end").val(moment(event.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD\THH:mm:ss"));`

Comment: I tried this, but still doesn't show. However, In the value for the modal I decided to do this 
`<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="start"  id="start" value="2020-10-04T12:00:00">`

and it displayed the value. 

I'm starting to think that it could be something else causing the problem.